# Force Google Chrome upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, updates, google-chrome

According to [this site](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2013/03/stable-channel-update_12.html) Chrome's current stable version for Linux is `25.0.1364.172` since March 12 (2013). It's the 18th now and I still have version `24.0.1312.52` in my system. I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade google-chrome-stable
```

but it says there's nothing to upgrade. What's the deal here?

Comment: Are you using the PPA for chrome?

Comment: There is no PPA for chrome, just the google repository, which is up to date.

Comment: Did you use `sudo apt-get update` before?

Comment: As @JorgeCastro says I have no Chrome PPA. TIIUNDER: yes I did. Also, since the 12th I've had several system updates and apparently none brought the new version. What version are you guys running (if you use Chrome that is)? Am I the only one having this issue?

Comment: I have the 25.0.1364.172

Comment: That makes it all the more strange o.O. What version of Ubuntu are you running? I have 12.10, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu 12.10 and have version 25.0.1364.172. I very much doubt your problem has anything to do with 12.10. Have you accidentally disabled `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/` in Software Sources? If you do that, you won't get offered updates.

Comment: @vasa1 I think that's where the problem is. Currently I have that source disabled (it says it was disabled when I upgraded to 12.10) and it won't let me re-enable it. I click but nothing happens. I can't remove or edit it either even though when I try to edit other PPAs it asks for `sudo` and works with no issue...

Comment: Okay, can you delete the entry from Software Sources? You may have to `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome` first. But for modifying Software Sources try to do it via the GUI unless you're totally comfortable with CLI.

Comment: No I can't. Neither that one nor several others in the same condition (ie: automatically disabled after distro upgrade) like the ones for `Dropbox` or `Wine` for example. I'd like to find a solution without having to purge Chrome. The GUI won't let do almost anything except un-checking already checked PPAs. The PPAs "disabled after upgrade" I can neither edit nor remove.

Comment: General answer given here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270516/cant-re-enable-ppas-long-after-upgrade-to-12-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270516/cant-re-enable-ppas-long-after-upgrade-to-12-10). I had to manually re-enable Chrome's PPA that had been disabled automatically after upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10. For some reason the software origins GUI wouldn't let me change it there so I had to edit the PPAs files by hand.