# Can't re-enable PPAs long after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, software-sources

I upgraded from `12.04` to `12.10` some time ago. I realize now that many of my PPAs were automatically disabled (as it always happens) Now, the issue is that I can't re-enable them, the `Software Sources` GUI won't let me. I can un-check already checked PPAs but that's it. I can't neither edit nor remove nor re-enable any of the automatically disabled PPAs.

For example, PPAs for `Google CHrome`, `Dropbox`, and `Wine` were disabled upon upgrading. On `Google Chrome` this reflects in my system still running version `24.0.1312.52` when the current version of this browser is `25.0.1364.172` (since March 12th)

How can I fix this?

---

By request here's the content of the `.list` files for `Dropbox`:

```
# deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu quantal main # (desactivado en la actualización a quantal)
```

and `Google Chrome`:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # (desactivado en la actualización a quantal)
```

FYI: "desactivado en la actualización a quantal" means "deactivated during quantal upgrade" in Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Old content removed, question revised and rewritten)

I see the items for DropBox and Google Chrome here, but not Wine.  Without the "Wine" entry, I can't help you figure out where you can reenable that.

In the mean time, in the lists for DropBox and Google Chrome, remove the # at the beginning of the line starting with `deb`, then save.  Then, `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`.  That should upgrade Chrome and DropBox correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "read the files in there" and "Delete the relevant lines for the PPAs in question"? For `Dropbox` and `Google Chrome` I have 3 files each: `.list`, `.list.distUpgrade` and `.list.save`. For `Google Chrome` the line `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main` is enabled only in the file `.list.distUpgrade`, the other two have that same line commented (same for `Dropbox`)

Comment: Those PPAs were added when I installed the apps and I don't know how they can be added manually. I'm not going to uninstall and re-install all apps, it seems overkill and another simpler solution must exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have your system in front of me.  The .save files should be kept as is, the .distUpgrade ones are meh, but likely unnecessary, but you should edit JUST the .list files.  Better idea: Include **as an edit to your question** the contents of JUST the `.list` files.  And make sure you ID which ones they are when you paste their contents.

Comment: added content as requested.

Comment: See revised answer, @Gabriel

Comment: Thanks Lord, I repeated the same thing for all disabled PPAs and it upgraded finally. Cheers!